# Problems with the uitextfield's responders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm creating a login for my app and I have a problem with the `UITextField's` responders.
I have 2 fields, one of them for the email and the other for the password. The first one, have the "next" button for the return, and the second one the "done" button.
The problem is that I am developing the logic for that buttons. The `textfieldShouldReturn` method is this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{    
    if ([emailField isFirstResponder]) {
        NSLog(@"NEXT");
    } else if ([passwordField isFirstResponder]) {
        [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Code about fields:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44);

emailField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[emailField setPlaceholder:@"Correo electronico"];
[emailField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[emailField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
[emailField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
[emailField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[emailField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[emailField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[emailField setDelegate:self];

passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[passwordField setPlaceholder:@"Contraseña"];
[passwordField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
[passwordField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[passwordField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
[passwordField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
[passwordField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[passwordField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[passwordField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[passwordField setDelegate:self];
```

When I am in the `emailField` and press the key next, nothing happens, but if I am in the `passwordField` and press the done key the app works fine and hides the keyboard.

Comment: Just you say if passwordField becomeFirstRespoder - passwordField resignFirstResponder :)

Comment: oh its over mate see the both frame is same mate..

Answer (score 0):

**This is my code**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == fieldUsername) {
        [fieldPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == fieldPassword) {
        [self doLogin];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The same...nothing happens when I click in the emailField's button. I have edited my question with more code about the fields

Comment: I checked Auto-enable Return Key in interface builder, it may help

Comment: I don't use xib for this case, I create them with code and add them to the table :/

Comment: fieldPassword.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;

Comment: Nothing...the same..,but I liked that feature :P

Comment: okay, did you assign UITextField delegate for your class? <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: Yes, I did. The passwordField works perfectly but the other doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{    
        if (textField == emailField) {
            NSLog(@"NEXT");
            [emailField resignFirstResponder];
            [passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else if (textField == passwordField) {
            [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When I am in the emailField, the app does nothing, it doesn't enter in the first condition

Comment: mmm but I add the fields to a cell, I mean, a field per cell, so the frame is about the cell, and they don't disturb themselves

Comment: it doesn't work with the second field, because I add these fields to cells, the first one to a cell and the second one to another cell, so the second field doesn't even appear in the cell if I use that frame.

Comment: oh ok then when you click on emailtectfiled then keypad is apear or not??

Comment: yes, the keyboard appears, and when I push the button "Next" nothing happens, and it must appears a warning in the console because I put an nslog inside the if. With the other field, the password, everything is correct.

Comment: @Juanjo now try my above code with another logic it is useful to you sure.. :)

Comment: nothing, the app doesnt enter in the if's first condition(emailField) but it does with the second one(passwordField)

Answer (score 0):

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {    
if ([emailField isFirstResponder]) {
    NSLog(@"NEXT");
   [passwordField becomefirstresponder];///add this 
} else if ([passwordField isFirstResponder]) {
    [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't enter in the first condition when I am in the emailField :/